# How to set up an Ubuntu 10.04 machine to accept ssh requests only from within the local network?

Tags: security, networking, ssh, firewall

I am about to install 10.04 (from bare metal to replace 9.04) and I want to set it up so that I can shh into the machine, but only from other machines on my local network. (I.e., I want to reject all ssh attempts from other than 192.168.1 set of IPs.) How do I do that correctly on 10.04?

Comment: The `hosts.allow/deny` answers are correct, but it also makes sense for your home gateway/router to silently ignore all inbound packets from port 22 (and most other ports too).

Comment: @msw: I did already have my router set up to silently ignore incoming requests, but putting that tip here was a good idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to edit the two configuration files `/etc/hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny` (you can get a detailed explanation of the format with `man hosts_access`):

**etc/hosts.allow:**

```
sshd: 192.168.1.
```

**etc/hosts.deny:**

```
sshd: ALL
```

In both cases you could replace `sshd` with `ALL`, then these rules would not only apply to the ssh server but to all other daemons that might be running.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to using hosts.allow and hosts.deny, you can use firewalls. "ufw" is installed by default in Ubuntu. You enable it with

> sudo ufw enable

and then limit the ssh connectivity with `

> sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24 to
>   any app OpenSSH

That should do it. I believe the FireStarter application will allow a GUI configuration of ufw as well.

Comment: is it worth mentioning that the application profile is now "OpenSSH"?